# Can someone explain this Feynman Diagram in the picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, notation, feynman-diagrams

[image]

I don’t understand this diagram at all, and what is the meaning of the $g$?

Comment: the g is an off shell gluon http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html

Answer (score 7):

The short line in the middle is a [gluon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon).

I don't know from where you got the diagram.
But it contains some mistakes.

- The anti[quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark) ($\bar{u}$ and $\bar{s}$) need to be drawn
  with their arrows pointing backwards in time.
- A gluon is conventionally drawn as a curly line (without an arrow).

So it would better be drawn like this.

[image]

The diagram shows how the particle collision
$$\pi^- + p \to K^0 + \Lambda^0$$
can be understood in terms of elementary particles
([quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark), antiquarks, [gluon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon)).
It breaks down the collision into the elementary processes
$$u + \bar{u} \to g$$
$$g \to s + \bar{s}$$

Comment: Could you explain why they go backwards in time, or should this be a whole separate question?  What little I know about physics makes me think only Tachyons go backwards in time (and we haven't found those to date).

Comment: Addendum: after reading @anna v's post above ( http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html ) it is clear to me that I don't know how to read Feynman diagrams properly, since time goes "up".  That said, the $\bar{s}$ interactions still seem to be moving backward in time.  What is going on?

Comment: @stux There are two conventions how to draw Feynman diagrams. Some people draw them with time from left to right (like here). Some people draw with time from bottom to top (like in anna's link).

Comment: @stux One of the rules for Feynman diagrams just says antiparticles
have their arrow pointing the opposite way than particles do.
See for example http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~barra/teaching/feynman.pdf .

Comment: The backwards in time is related to CPT symmetry - in simple terms, if you reversed time, and then changed all particles to anti-particles then physics stays the same, so an anti-particle going forward in time is a particle going backwards in time (if you've seen Tenet that's what's happening at those doors). Feynmann diagrams can have time going left to right or top to bottom as mentioned. I'm trying to remember if there is also a convention where you can draw anti-particles going forwards in time, as long as you label the anti-particle clearly (fundamentally I think its just the dual irrep)

Comment: Thank you Thomas-Fritsch and @N-A-McMahon for your responses and clarification!  At least I can say I understand things a tiny bit better and now I have an article to read for homework! :)